# Reduction formula for integral of $\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} dx $

Tags: integration, radicals

The following reduction formula is taken from http://www.sosmath.com/tables/integral/integ15/integ15.html:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} dx = -\frac{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}{cx} - \frac{b}{2c} \int \frac{1}{x \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}} dx$$

1. I've been trying to derive this reduction formula myself, but without success. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
2. Are there similar formulae for higher exponents of the $x$ in the denominator? Or even better, for general integer exponents $n$?

Comment: You can find your desired reduction formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae

Comment: That should be a minus sign, not a plus sign in front of $b\over 2c$. The second term on the right hand side of your equation.

Comment: Are you the same man here-https://www.integral-calculator.com/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}{cx}\right)'&=\frac{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}{c x^2}-\frac{2ax+b}{2cx\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}
\\\\&=\frac{2(ax^2+bx+c)-(2ax+b)x}{2cx^2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}
\\\\&=\frac{bx+2c}{2cx^2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}
\\\\&=\frac{b}{2c}\cdot\frac{1}{x \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}+\frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}
\end{align}
$$ which yields the first result.

This might be generalized to get 
$$
\begin{align}
\left(-\frac{\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}{cx^{\color{red}{n}+1}}\right)'&=\frac{a\cdot \color{red}{n}}{cx^{\color{red}{n}}\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}+\frac{b}{2c}\cdot\frac{(2\color{red}{n}+1)}{x^{\color{red}{n}+1} \sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}+\frac{\color{red}{n}+1}{x^{\color{red}{n}+2}\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The denominator has a factor of $c x^2$, not $c^2 x$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you very much! Edited.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> It's convenient to rewrite the original question as
>   $$
> \int{\dd x \over x^{2}\root{ax^{2} + bx + c}} =
> {1 \over \root{a}}
> \color{#f00}{\int{\dd x \over x^{2}\root{x^{2} + 2px + q}}}\,,\qquad
> p \equiv {b \over 2a}\,,\quad q \equiv {c \over a}
> $$

Lets
$\ds{t = \root{x^{2} + 2px + q} - x \iff
x = -\,{1 \over 2}\,{t^{2} - q \over t - p}}$:

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\int{\dd x \over x^{2}\root{x^{2} + 2px + q}}}  =
-4\int{t - p \over \pars{t^{2} - q}^{2}}\,\dd t =
-\,{2 \over q}\,{pt - q \over t^{2} - q} + {2p \over q^{3/2}}\,
\,\mrm{arctanh}\pars{t \over \root{q}}
\end{align}
Replace $\ds{t = \root{x^{2} + 2px + q} - x}$ in the *right hand side*.